# Semantic object Intent navigation CDS annotation

Tags: sapui5, cds, rap

I am trying below code to bring a custom button to oven the file upload GUI screen. I've done the configuration for semantic object and below is the code reference to call that.

This is how it's looking. Now action button for file upload.

Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

[image]

```
  @Consumption.semanticObject: 'ztestesem'
  @UI.lineItem: [
  { position: 40 },
                { type: #FOR_ACTION,
                  dataAction: 'withPopup' ,
                  label: 'Update'},
                  { type: #FOR_ACTION,  dataAction: 'clearProject' , label: 'Clear' , position: 80 , invocationGrouping:#CHANGE_SET },
 
 { 
    position: 20,
    label: 'File upload',
    type: #FOR_INTENT_BASED_NAVIGATION,
    semanticObjectAction: 'display'                -- Action
  } ]
  
  Zzproject;
```